# How to make a link act as a file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a link,

```
<a id="upload-file">Upload your photo</a>
```

And if clicked, I want it to act as an browse file input

```
<input id="upload-file" type="file"/>
```

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input id="upload" type="file"/>
<a href="" id="upload_link">Upload your photo</a>​
```

**CSS**

```
#upload{
    display:none
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $("#upload_link").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#upload:hidden").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

[**​DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7aGEv/3/)

Comment: Really smart solution. Its clearly the right answer, and I would have spent hours trying to figure this out from scratch. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

**HTML Only**

Here's a pretty simple answer that works with no CSS, Javascript/jQuery and doesn't rely on any framework infrastructure.

```
<label>
  <input type="file" style="display: none;">
  <a>Upload Photo link</a>
</label>
```

or even simpler

```
<label>
  <input type="file" style="display: none;">
  Upload Photo link
</label>
```

Comment: IMO, the best answer

Answer (score 7):

following will solved the problem

html

```
<input id="upload-file" type="file"/>
<a id="fileupload">Upload your photo</a>
```

css

```
#upload-file{
    display: none;
}​
```

js

```
$("#fileupload").click(function(){
    $("#upload-file").click();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WXBKj/

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without Javascript like this. cross-browser solution with attribute `for` :

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j9pu8hgx/)

**HTML**

```
<label for="inputUpload" class="custom-file-upload">Upload your file</label>
<input id="inputUpload" type="file" />
```

**CSS**

```
#inputUpload {
    display: none;
}

.custom-file-upload {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: #0c090d;
}

.custom-file-upload:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j9pu8hgx/)

Answer (score 2):

You can have a hidden `<input>` tag that you can then call `$('#upload').click()` on in order to simulate a click.

Or, you can have a hidden `<input>` tag that has an id, and then just add a label attribute to your link.

Comment: Please give an example of your second option.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 6, you can do like this,

```
<li class="list-group-item active cursor-pointer" (click)="file.click()">
    <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i> Upload <input type="file" #file hidden />
  </li>
```

When you click li html tag, the input button's click is triggered."**hidden**" attribute makes invisible.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

See This Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/s6Mjt/

**JQUERY:**

```
$("#upload").click(function(){
    $("#upload-file").trigger('click');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="upload">Upload your photo</a>
<input id="upload-file" type="file"/>
```

**CSS**

```
#upload-file {
    display:none;
}
```

**OR**

You may use nice plugins like this:

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/